# Can I use data licensed under Creative Commons for closed source propriety software?

Tags: creative-commons, cc-by-sa, cc-by

I am interested in using data distributed under the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 (CC-By-SA) license. A subset of it can be extracted, which will fall under a Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 license (CC-By) instead.

I will be using this data for commercial, closed-source software.  Only data will be used, and there is no software that will be depended on by my software.

Given that I will not be modifying or distributing the data (consumers of the software will not be able to view the data), but will only use it to automatically perform data analysis and modify another dataset that I own, what conditions would be applicable to my usage of it?

Edit: to clarify, the use of the data would result in my software being different than if it didn't use the data

Comment: Can you be more specific? When you say "a subset can be extracted" you mean this subset is licensed under CC-BY by the authors? Is the software that you are making and distributing going to be different because you used the data (such as an AI program)? In that case, it could be considered to be a derivative work.

Comment: The dataset in question is ConceptNet, which aggregates and links information from different sources. Part of the dataset is licensed under CC-BY. (https://github.com/commonsense/conceptnet5/wiki/Copying-and-sharing-ConceptNet). I am indeed going to make AI-powered software, and make it available to customers

Comment: Did you copy the correct url for the similar question? That link goes to wikipedia :D

Comment: Sorry here is the link to the similar question http://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/5208/5858 (similar but not a duplicate)

Comment: You say that you won't distribute the data, but do you mean that you won't distribute it in an accessible manner? If it's included in what your users purchase, even if hidden or buried deep within some other data, the CC BY-SA license still applies.

Comment: Thank you both @Zimmi48 and @curiousdannii! So if I understand this correctly, my work will then be considered a derivative of the dataset. Under CC-BY, I will then have to provide attribution to the dataset and its authors somewhere in my software. If I use the full CC-BY-SA data, I will have to distribute my software under CC-BY-SA.

Comment: If one of you will submit an answer (instead of a comment), I will accept it as the correct answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, as was said in the comments, your software will "contain the data in a hidden way" or be better because the data was used to train it. Thus, your software will be a derivative of the data and if this data is licensed under CC-BY-SA the share-alike clause applies, whereas if you use the subset which is licensed under CC-BY, you only have an attribution requirement when making a derivative work.